# ESLint terminated with error: timeout in brackets?

Tags: javascript, timeout, eslint

im new for javaScript and when i ran the code in brackets it keep showing me this error , how to fix it please ?

```
var greeting = "";
var highScore = 435;
var myScore = 200;

if (myScore < highScore) {
    greeting = "oops";
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = greeting;
```

Comment: forgot to copy code?

Comment: its basic code , i will add it now

Comment: error as well..

Comment: Please try `brackets-eslint@1.5.0`, hope this fixes your issue!

Comment: it worked thank you <3 <3

Comment: Please refer this link. this solution worked for me.[eslint errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067263/eslint-showing-errors-in-brackets)

Answer (score 1):

Please try again using,

```
brackets-eslint@1.5.0
```